# Can't do backtrack research in OCaml

Tags: search, ocaml, backtracking, depth

I am trying to solve the puzzle 15 game in OCaml. I almost did everything.. except for the core function of the program, the depth first search function.
This is what my function looks like now:

```
let df_search_path (Graph next) start =
    let rec from_node visited a =
            print(a);
             if List.mem a visited then raise Fail
             else if goal(a) then [a]
                  else a::from_list (a::visited) (next a)
        and from_list visited nextA = match visited with
            [] -> raise Fail
                | nextA::rest -> try from_node visited nextA
                          with Fail -> from_list visited rest
in from_node [] start;;
```

`Graph` is a graph, `next` is a function that searches for the 2,3 or 4 next moves (I move the empty space), `goal` is a function to check if current `a` state is the goal and `Fail` is a normal exception.

I tried a lot all the other functions and they works well.

This function endlessy loops always in the starting state, and I can't understand why. 
`print` is a custom function to print the state `a` in a friendly form.

What am I doing wrong? I'm making my test using a state "1 move" far from the solution, just a "go down" will solve this.. but it is stuck in the first state, always printing the start configuration!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect your error is only the `match visited with ..` instead of `match nextA with ...` in `from_list`.

```
let df_search_path (Graph next) start =
    let rec from_node visited a =
            print(a);
            if List.mem a visited then raise Fail
            else if goal(a) then [a]
            else a::from_list (a::visited) (next a)
        and from_list visited nextA = match nextA with
            | [] -> raise Fail
            | nextA::rest -> try from_node visited nextA
                             with Fail -> from_list visited rest
in from_node [] start;;
```

That said, there are other ways the code could be improved: currently, "visited" only stores the node that have been visited *by this search path*, instead of all the nods visited so far; moving to a data structure that is preserved globally and shared between all the "children searches" of any node would reduce the number of useless searches (if you only want a path that leads to the goal).

Finally, using a list here is a rather bad idea as `List.mem` takes time linear in the size of the list; this gives an overall quadratic behavior. You should rather use a data structure specialized in membership checking, such as `Set` (or maybe a datastructure that corresponds to your problem domain: in labyrinth-like searches for example, a matrix of booleans is usually simpler and more efficient).

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to see exactly how this code is supposed to work. Here's something I see:

You calculate a list of nodes to visit (it appears) with `next a`. In the `from_list` function, you don't use this list. Instead you rename the first element of the `visited` list as `nextA` and revisit that. It seems you're simply revisiting the first already visited node over and over. I don't see why `from_list` would care about the visited nodes at all. Most likely it would just pass the list along to `from_node`.